# Updating cloned element when original Element is modified

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I am new to Jquery and would enjoy a few leads to put me on the right track :)

Issue: I have a cart total price which is shown on another place of the page thanks to `clone()` and I would like to have this cloned price to auto-update each time the original price element is modified.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
  var $vartocopy = $('#totalpricemodule').clone(true);
  $('.column42').append($vartocopy);
});
```

Comment: How is the original updated? You need to amend the logic to also amend the clone. There's no built in manner of linking two objects.

Comment: As a beginner I cannot answer you, but I was just wondering if a jquery function would allow to replicate a Dom node and keep updating informations from it instead of just cloning it and having to refresh the page to get it updated.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a manual process

Comment: Are all modifications done in the code? Or are these inputs that the user can modify as well?

Comment: By the way it is NOT a good idea to clone an element that has an ID and place it as it is back into the html. This will mean you have two elements with the same ID. This is against the principles although it wouldn't directly throw a bug.

Comment: This is not a good practice. What you should do is having the 2 html div's or whatever with some unique id's and a method from where you update both id's with the sum.

Comment: That is a smell that you architecture is bad. But you could just create a function that will sync the two elements. You call that function everytime the price is changed. A better solution could be to encapsulate your component and use mvc pattern with an observer pattern. Just google these terms.

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches you can take from where you are facing your issue. However, there is one thing sure, JavaScript does not provide any magic that you require here and JQuery neither.

## 1. Move to data-centric thinking(reactive)

Long story short, your problem originates in the fact that you don't have a single source of truth([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth)) for price. It means that you are actually displaying 2 different prices which have the same value only because you mean them to. Those 2 prices have 2 representations in memory of your program and this fact is what causes all the problems you have.

Data-centric approach in your case - or reactive thinking as some people prefer - would be storing your price in JS variable/object/whatever(or generally speaking store it in memory of your JS program instead of DOM) and only at this one place. Now, whoever and whatever wants to display or use that value needs to access that variable/object/whatever.

I believe the misconception that many JS developers have is that JS code is not really a program, it's just a sugar coat over the DOM(and JQuery doesn't mitigate this). In my opinion it's wrong. One should use DOM for displaying things just as browsers do. So, store your data in memory, use JS for running code and display things via DOM.

There are many libraries out there who can make it all actually work without much difficulty. However, this is not without a cost. Firstly, you need to learn a new library, secondly you have yet another dependency and thirdly this makes your site more dependant on JS itself. Though, it's worth it. Even if just for the sake of being better programmer.

The library that I want to recommend is [Vue](https://vuejs.org/). Not without a reason. Vue is easy to learn, lightweight, fast, doesn't force on you any "framework" and has decent documentation. Of course all of this is possible because core of Vue is not as feature-rich as other libraries but I believe it's perfect for your needs now.

With Vue you can hold your price in one variable and whenever you update that variable all places where it is used will be updated automatically. I think this is the magic that you want.

## 2. Create a function to update your value

Create a function like `updatePrice` which will update all places that need to be updated. How you will hold the references is up to you. If there are only several places you can just update them explicitly. Though, that assumes that there is only one price to display. If there are many different prices i.e. some products list then this gets only harder. In the end you might end up reinventing the wheel and create something similar to what Vue and other such libraries have to offer.

## 3. Eliminate problem without solving it

You can always decide that you only need this price displayed at one place eliminating the problem itself. Without problem there is nothing to solve.